# Correct terms to refer the implications $\implies$ and $\impliedby$ in a "if and only if" statement.

Tags: terminology

My writing a proof of a complex proposition of the type "$A \iff B$" for a paper.
I want to close a block of argumentation with a sentence like "Which concludes the first implication". Here I am calling the "$\implies$" as the first implication, but I don't know if this is the correct term to use.

What is the correct term to refer to the "$\implies$" and the "$\impliedby$" implication in the mentioned context?

Comment: You can also refer to them as forward and reverse implications.

Comment: "with the forward direction shown, we now prove the other direction"

Comment: Another way I've seen people do this in papers is to put $(\Rightarrow)$ and $(\Leftarrow)$ at the beginning of paragraphs, almost as bullet points. You would see an indent, then $(\Rightarrow)$:, followed by a space, then the proof that $A \implies B$ would begin from there.

Comment: @TheoBendit, It is a good suggestion, but I was trying to avoid "splitting" the demonstration into two parts for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BrevanEllefsen answered in comments, $\Rightarrow$ is the *forward implication* while $\Leftarrow$ is the *reverse implication*.

In practice, I like @TheoBendit's suggestion of preceding the paragraph where you start proving one of the implications by $(\Rightarrow)$ or $(\Leftarrow)$ (with appropriate formatting like indent,...) very much, especially on my personal notes or drafts.

On the other hand, if your proof is well-constructed, this could be superfluous. Frame the proof of each implication by the necessary assumptions and conclusion ("Assume A. Then [...]. This implies that B") and separate the two proofs by "Conversely", or similar expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The $\implies$ direction is called *sufficiency*, and the $\impliedby$ direction is called *necessity*.

Answer (score 1):

I would say something as: ($\dots$) *which concludes the previous "if A, then B" statement*.

Remark 1: From here on, we indicate the forward/direct implication as "$A \Rightarrow$ B", whereas we use "$A \Leftarrow$ B" for its opposite relation (i.e., a reverse relation between proposition A and proposition B).